# deleting new line charecter(\n) from csv

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a csv files as below

```
1,I am 
Rakesh
Reddy,Dayton
```

and it is expected as  `1,I am Rakesh Reddy, Dayton`

Is there a option to remove the \n character using power shell script or batch command?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The newline character (`\n` in most languages, backtick-n  in PowerShell) is used to separate and terminate the records in a CSV file.

Comment: Is it a hidden CSV file?

Comment: How do you expect PowerShell to know what new line characters to remove, and which ones to keep?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of newline characters embedded inside text fields in a CSV file?  It's not clear from your question.

Comment: Yes I am trying to get rid of new line charterers embedded inside the text fileds in a csv file..

Comment: If the fields do not have some sort of delimiter but contain newlines, the csv file is malformed.

Comment: Okay so your opening question is misleading then, because you are not wanting to get rid of the new line characters from the csv, you still need to keep those where you expect the end of each line to be. To do this successfully you will probably need to find a way of determining the proper number of delimiters in each file and replace until that number has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

If your text above is in a string variable, say `$String`, then you can remove the newline characters using this line of code:

```
$NewString = $String -replace "`r`n", ''
```

This replaces all carriage returns (\r) and new line characters (\n) from the string with an empty string. Then you can pipe the variable `$NewString` to a CSV using the Export-Csv cmdlet.